# NASA Data is not loading

Tags: r, json, dataframe

I am trying to load data from Nasa into R using;

```
metadata <- fromJSON("https://data.nasa.gov/data.json")
```

The error that i am getting is:

```
Error in readBin(3L, raw(0), 32768L) : cannot read from connection
In addition: Warning message:
In readBin(3L, raw(0), 32768L) :
  URL 'https://data.nasa.gov/data.json': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
```

What do i do?

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate of timeout error, `httr::HEAD("https://data.nasa.gov/data.json")` is giving me a 400 Bad request error.

Comment: `options(timeout = 100L)` solves the issue for me. Without it, I get the same timeout error as reported above.